# In Emacs, Listing Buffers in the minibuffer

Tags: emacs, minibuffer

I am a college student and am just back from my internship.

There, I extensively used emacs and I had never used Emacs before.
So I am not sure which version of emacs it was.

There was this cheat I don't remember (C-x ???), which would show a list of all the buffers in the minibuffer. Kind of like:

```
(*scratch*,*Messages*,afile.c,buffer2)
```

Out of all one would be highlighted, to which one could jump by hitting return.

And to go through over buffers I used C-n.

Now when I installed emacs23 in my system, I can't find the said cheat. Moreover, I went Google-Searching for the same thing. But, nothing relevant showed up (except C-x b and C-x C-b).

**Note:** It was not the conventional buffer list produced by ***C-x C-b***. Nor, was it the switch-to option of ***C-x b***.

Can you help me with recalling the cheat?

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are asking about `iswitchb`. Try

```
M-x iswitchb-mode
M-x iswitchb-buffer
```

If I'm right then just put `(iswitchb-mode 1)` in .emacs.

You will notice that this mode changes key definition, for example `C-x b` to `(iswitchb-buffer)`.

You can read more here:
http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/IswitchBuffers

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much.